# Considerations about real polynomial with complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $p\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ - polynomial with real coefficients.
$p(x)=(x-z_1)(x-z_2)(x-z_3)(x-z_4)(x-z_5), $.
$z_k\in \mathbb{C} $ for each $k=1,2,3,4,5$.  Then:
**a.** among numbers $z_k$ there is real number ($k=1,..,5$).
**b.** it is possible that exactly two of $z_k$ are real.  ($k=1,..,5)$.
**c.** product $z_1z_2z_3z_4z_5$ is real number.

Can you help me ? I can't deal with it. The only way that comes to my mind is to product $p(x)$ and then consider it. But I think that it is not solution that I should find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question a: First of all, $f$ having real coefficients:

If $f(z_k)=0$, then $\bar f(z_k)=0$, i.e. $f(\bar z_k)=0$
meaning that if $z_k$ is a root of $f$, so is $\bar z_k$.

Consider the example of the 5th degree polynomial factor into 5 first degree factors like this:

$$p(x)=x^5-4x^4+8x^3-10x^2+7x-6=(x-2)(x^2+1)(x^2-2x+3)$$

$$p(x)=(x-2)(x-i)(x-(-i))(x-(1+i\sqrt{2}))(x-(1-i\sqrt{2}))$$

There is a real root (2) and 4 non-real roots.

The non real roots go by conjugate pairs (what I call "twins"), $i$ with $-i$, $1+i\sqrt{2}$ with $1-i\sqrt{2}$. Thus there is necessarily a parenthesis that is twined with... no other because there is an **odd** number of parentheses.

There is another - graphical - reason.

Consider the graphical representation of $f$. Because $f(x)$ is equivalent to $x^5$ at $\pm \infty$:

- when $x \to -\infty$, $f(x) \to -\infty,$
- when $x \to +\infty$, $f(x) \to +\infty.$

thus, $f$ being continuous, there is at least one real value $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ (see figure).

[image]

Question b: No, because of the pairing described above, if the first factor corresponds to a real root, if the second factor corresponds to a real root, then the third, which is conjugate to the second, will also correspond to a real root (the same one, i.e., we will have a double root). Which makes (at least) 3 real roots (because roots are counted with their order of multiplicity).

Question c: Yes, because $z_1z_2z_3z_4z_5=z_1z_2 \bar z_2 z_4 \bar z_4=z_1 |z_2|^2 |z_4|^2 \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: So, for polynomial with real coefficients - roots has always twin? It means that if $5+i$ is root then $5-i$ is also root ? (very importan are real coefficient)

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1):

For a) and b), think about what must be true of the complex roots for the polynomial $p(x)$ to be real. Hint: $p(x)$ is invariant under complex conjugation, hence so is the right hand side. What does this say about the roots on the.

For c), try expanding the right hand side.

Comment: Better: For (c), note that the specified product is the constant $-p(0)$. Can it be nonreal?

Comment: The important thing to underline is that $p(x)$ has an odd degree (5)...Thus, as complex roots are twined, $(x - z_k)(x - \bar z_k)$ , there remains a factor $(x - z_k)$ that cannot be grouped with no other.

Comment: @JeanMarie, can you be more precisely ? I dont understand you

Comment: I have esplained it an an "answer" based on an example.